# Where is the royality amount defined?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, royalties

i'm currently diving into the whole topic NFT, blockchain and smart contracs. I also played around with some smart contracts on my own ganache blockchain. Everything is more or less clear to me, but one thing what I couldn't find, is the declartion or implementation of the royality amount. Where excatly is this defined?

When i'm on OpenSea it seems, the marketplace has some kind of own implementation between my smart contract and there own's, because I can define what the creator royality is about, fine, but when I build my own contract with OpenZepplin or I also took the example from ([HashLips](https://github.com/HashLips/solidity_smart_contracts), I could not find any declartion of the royality amount.

It seems for Openzepplin, they suggest to override `transferFrom` to modify this, but anyway every smart contract it seems has a royality amount, which is normaly around 2.5 to 5%, but as I check some smart contracts via EtherScan, I could not find any implementation.

And just to be sure, with royality amount, I mean the kind of provision, which I always get as a creator when the nft is being traded.

Would be great, if someone could solve the riddle for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw this implementation: [Contract](https://github.com/nsinthunont/nft-royalties/blob/main/contracts/NFT.sol)

Basically we override the `transferFrom` function to iclude paying to the artist:

```
function transferFrom(
    address from, 
    address to, 
    uint tokenId
) public override {

    require(from != address(0x0), 'invalid from address');
    require(to != address(0x0), 'invalid to address');

    require(tokenId > 0, 'invalid tokenId');
    require(tokenId <= _tokenIds.current(), 'invalid tokenId');

    require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), 'msgSender is not the owner of the token');

    if(excludeList[tokenId] == false) {
        _payTxFee(from);//Pays the artist
    }

    _transfer(from, to, tokenId);

}

function _payTxFee(address from) internal {
    IERC20 token = IERC20(txFeeToken);
    token.transferFrom(from, artist, txFeeAmount);
}
```

If you do not wish to have a single artist for all nfts minted on the specific contract, you can also override `_mint` and set a different artist to each NFT.

Comment: Hi Julissa, thanks for you answer. Ok, so my guess is, that a royality is the default case when offering the nft over a dapp. When the minting is done on the dapp, the creator gets usually the royality amount, cause open sea offers such functionality. Am I wrong?